# Site design and logo — Draft

Tags: discussion, design

I'm Simon, a designer at Stack Overflow and I've been working on designing a theme for this community!

### Your site design

As mentioned in our [first post](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5314/58986) - below you'll find the site design I came up with based on your original ideas for *Philosophy*.

For this theme, I wanted to go back to philosophy's roots with a few inspirations from Ancient Greece. Hoping this still translates well into today's modern view of philosophy? If not, let us know!

### Color scheme

[image]

The palette uses calming colours of blue, white, grey and brown. Characterizing the sky, clouds, stone and earth.

### Logo

[image]

I wonder what you all think this logo represent? Leave a comment with your thoughts!

### Favicon

[image]

The *Phi* greek letter seemed like the perfect choice for an icon.

### Page Design

[image]

[image]

*Home and question page design with serif font*

### Special pages illustrations.

[image: [Insert image of error page if you worked on this]]

From left to right:

- Page not found: "We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested."
- Human verification: "Are you a human being?"
- Error: "Oops! Something Bad Happened!"

We hope you enjoy this design, but if something doesn’t feel right, now is your chance to share your feedback. This window for feedback will be open one week. We will then work to incorporate feedback as best as we can, finalize things on our end, and lastly, deliver the design to your site.

Comment: Thanks, Simon -- beautiful work!

Comment: This is surprisingly good.

Comment: I will probably always read the title as *philphsophy,* but then that’s probably just me.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft It is not just you, he's using a capital letter Phi, after all :D

Comment: hmm, the phi letter there makes me think dirty

Comment: This is a masterpiece!!

Comment: Update: [Your new site design is live!](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5365/31765)

Comment: Why is phi a perfect choice for an icon? Because phi is a Greek symbol and Ancient Greece was very significant for philosophy? If we consider what it already means, it apparently has a meaning in philosophy, but one that seems to be fairly obscure. It's used quite extensively in mathematics, though, and without any further context, I'd probably have assumed that's what the site relates to. If I were going to pick a Greek symbol, I'd probably have gone with one that isn't so well-known, like psi (Ψ) or something - psi kind of looks like a trident, which is quite strongly associated with Greece.